# Command line parser, port number retrieving

Tags: c, parsing, unix

I'm trying to implement a simple parsing scheme for port number input from command line. I'm just wondering if this code below can be fine or there are any errors or imprecision.

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int sock_ds, opt;
char *cmd_port;
unsigned short port;


/*Parsing command line: port-number retrieving*/
while (( opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:")) != -1){
    switch(opt){
        case 'p':
            port = (unsigned short) strtoul(optarg, &optarg, 0); //string to unsigned long integer with ushort cast
            if(*optarg){
                fprintf(stderr, "String-integer conversion error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -p port_number\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

printf("Port number retrieved (%d), server is starting ...\n", port);
    /* ... */
}
```

Thanks for your support!

Re-editet with `getopt(3)` in a loop. This should work. There are other suggestions?

Comment: Use `getopt(3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the example from the documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt

In particular, you are not calling getopt() in a loop, and you're not checking for "bad" options with '?'.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is using sscanf() and checking its return value ( := the number of assignments it made):

```
unsigned short port;
int opt;
opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:");
if(opt == 'p'){
    int rc;
    rc = sscanf( optarg, "%hu", &port);
    if (rc < 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "String-integer conversion error for %s\n", optarg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```